# Setup null modem connection with a phone like cable

Tags: phone, rs232, null-modem

I have a device that I want to connect with, reading the user's manual it claims that I can connect to the device via SR-232 interface and it list all the steps to configure a null modem connection on widows 7 an use that connection with its own software, so far so good, the only problem I have is that most null modem connections that I have seen on the internet, are done with cables like these:

[image]

but the device does not have a port like that, instead it has a port like this:

[image]

That's right its like a phone jack with a label below it that says "RS232", so I wonder if I need a special cable ? Because my computer does not have an entry like that.

Comment: That 'phone jack' is probably an RJ-45 type connector (usually 8 wires), it looks like an oversized 'phone plug' (which is an RJ-11 type, max 6 wires).  And @Ignacio (hey!) is correct about the wiring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a special cable, but a special adapter. 4 signal lines is enough to run a RS-232 connection, but they need to be wired to the appropriate pins on the D-Sub connector. [Example here](http://www.nexstarsite.com/PCControl/RS232Cable.htm), but use the pinout appropriate for your device.